# Recorrer listas dentro de un diccionario python

Tags: python, lista

Si tengo este diccionario con **python**:

```
{'143534':[23,12,45],'123765':[33,89,90],'148987':[98,65,80]}
```

Necesito colocar una matríz así:

```
23,33,98
12,89,65
45,90,80
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> d = {'143534': [23, 12, 45], '123765': [33, 89, 90], '148987':[98, 65, 80]}
>>> d.values()
[[23, 12, 45], [33, 89, 90], [98, 65, 80]]
>>> zip(*d.values())
[(23, 33, 98), (12, 89, 65), (45, 90, 80)]
```

Con el método `values` obtienes los valores por cada elemento del diccionario. Ahora, como `zip` espera una cierta cantidad de iterables (listas o tuplas), estamos pasando cada una usando `*`. Es decir, lo que se está pasando a `zip` es:

```
>>> zip([23, 12, 45], [33, 89, 90], [98, 65, 80])
[(23, 33, 98), (12, 89, 65), (45, 90, 80)]
```